# How can I pass file through Node.js without download it?

Tags: node.js, multer

I have an endpoint that take file and will store it into Object storage, So in node to revice file from request I used 
multer module that download file first into folder to can use it.

So how can I pass the file from endpoint to the function that will send it to object storage without download it as shown below?
and send it as a parameter in addingObject function
my endpoint

```
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/addingObject', upload.single('file'), async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    logger.info({ message: 'beginning of POST/addingObject' });
    console.log('Hi--->', req.body);
    const response = newToCountryController.addingObject(req.file);
    res.status(201).json(response);
    return next();
  } catch (error) {
    logger.debug({
      error,
      message: error.message
    });
    const errorDetails = defaultErrorHandler(error, error.message);
    return next(errorDetails);
  }
});
```

Comment: And what exactly is object storage?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set `dest` then multer will store the file in memory.

The contents will be available in the `file.buffer` property.